# A :focus-within workaround for edge

Tags: css, google-chrome, css-selectors, microsoft-edge

I am currently using the pseudo selector :focus-within in chrome however according to [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-focus-within) it's unavailable in Edge and IE, I found a neat workaround for it:

```
.focus-within-class > input:focus
```

However it combining it with focus-within like:

```
.focus-within > input:focus,
.focus-within:focus-within > input
```

does not work in Edge and the following solution does not work in chrome:

```
.focus-within > input:focus
```

How can I make :focus-within cross browser?

Comment: Your codepen link is broken.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Couple of things. First, the "workaround" that you cite isn't really equivalent to `:focus-within` as the resulting rules apply to the `<input>` element. You could just as easily do

```
input:focus {
    /* rules here */
}
```

without bothering about the special classes. The real `:focus-within` pseudo-classs allows you to define rules that apply to the containing element, *not* the `<input>`

But if the particular workaround does have utility for you, you'll need to break your rules into separate blocks. That's because browsers silently ignore any CSS they don't understand. So when Edge sees

```
.focus-within > input:focus,
.focus-within:focus-within > input
```

it notices that there's a pseudo class that it doesn't understand (`:focus-within`), so it ignores the entire rule block, as you've noticed. If you split the rules into two blocks, Edge will only ignore the block it doesn't understand.

```
.focus-within > input:focus {
    /* rules here, which Edge will apply */
}

.focus-within:focus-within > input
    /* same rules here, which Edge will ignore */
}
```

Comment: Hi Stephen, is there any way so that we can set style on siblings.. we have same issue but we are putting style for siblings and it's working fine in other browsers but not working in edge.

Comment: @AvneshShakya, open a question for that. The generic sibling selector `~` [should work, even in Edge or IE](https://caniuse.com/#search=sibling).

Comment: This is a great answer and a bit of a facepalm over here.