# How to display an element when his children is focused by keyboard navigation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, accessibility

**Update** cause I still have no clue how to do this and I would be glad to know it. Just a reminder this is about accessibility and using keyboard only (no mouse), things that people doesn't seem to understand so far, making this question fall into abyss even if IMO this is interesting.

I try to improve the accessibility of my website and I've an issue with a div displayed only when itself or the previous element are focused/hovered.

There is an input into this div and I want it to be accessible by **keyboard** navigation, but when the focus go on the input,
it does not consider that the div is so.

So I'm asking how can I detect when the focus go on this input and keep the parent div displayed ?

I've already tried with css but we can't select parent (except with :had but it's not implemented yet).

I've also search a solution with JavaScript and jQuery but I didn't figure out how to achieve this.

```css
.b {
  display: none;
}

.a:hover+.b,
.a:focus+.b,
.b:hover,
.b:focus {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<button class="a">A button that displays the div</button>
<div class="b">
  <input type="checkbox">
</div>
```

Actually the div appear when you focus the button, but when you go on the input with tabulation, the div disappear. I want it to stay displayed while the input is focused.

It's working if you click on the button, issue only happen when you don't use your mouse.

I've found :focus-within but it's [not implemented on all browser](https://caniuse.com/#search=focus-within).

Comment: It seems to work. When I click on the button, the checkbox appears.

Comment: I don't see the problem. Works for me on Chrome.

Comment: The title doesn't make sense. If a parent isn't visible, the child won't be visible either, so you can't focus on the child.

Comment: your question doesn't explain the problem you are facing. downvoting this question. apologies.

Comment: Seems you have browser compatibility issue.

Comment: To avoid more misunderstanding, I made the title more specific.

Answer (score 0):

So your problem is when you click in the checkbox i.e. when checkbox is checked then it should be `display: block` until it is checked. When you uncheck it again it should work like before i.e. on button focus `display: block` else `display: none` Am I correct?

Comment: No sorry, I think my question isn't clear enough, it's when we focus the input with keyboard navigation (tabulation). The div disappear.

Comment: I think this link should help you [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50788621/10071641)

Comment: Thanks for the link Harshada, but it only say how to override focus-within property when it doesn't work.
I've found a workaround in my case, I've make the parent div focusable and the checkbox unfocusable. And when we click (or press space) on the parent div a JS function emulate a click on the checkbox.